# Renaming/prefixing SimpleMembership tables

Tags: asp.net-mvc

Is there a way to prefix SimpleMembership tables, I would like to create 'ProjectName_AspNetUsers' instead of 'AspNetUsers'?

Comment: Honestly, don't user `SimpleMembership` any more, my advice is to use Identity v2 instead.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you must configure web.cnofig > membership section like bellow:

```
<membership defaultProvider="MySqlMembershipProvider">
  <providers>
    <clear/>
    <add name="myMembershipProvider"
         type="MySql.Web.Security.MySQLMembershipProvider,
           MySql.Web, Version=6.3.4.0, Culture=neutral,
           PublicKeyToken=c5687fc88969c44d"
         autogenerateschema="true"
         tablePrefix="ProjectName_"
         connectionStringName="ApplicationServices"
         enablePasswordRetrieval="false"
         enablePasswordReset="true"
         requiresQuestionAndAnswer="false"
         requiresUniqueEmail="false"
         passwordFormat="Hashed"
         maxInvalidPasswordAttempts="5"
         minRequiredPasswordLength="6"
         minRequiredNonalphanumericCharacters="0"
         passwordAttemptWindow="10"
         passwordStrengthRegularExpression=""
         applicationName="sparkSources"
 />
  </providers>
</membership>
```