# How to prefix .Net Core Identity tables

Tags: asp.net-core

Is there a way to prefix .Net Core Identity tables, instead of 'AspNetUsers' being created as a database name, I would like to end up with 'ProjectName_AspNetUsers'

Comment: You literally just asked the [same question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40938456/renaming-prefixing-simplemembership-tables) about `SimpleMembership`, what are you trying to do exactly?

Comment: Yes, I should ask about Identity instead of SimpleMebership. i am developing .Net Core App this time, do you know how to achieve that?

Comment: You switched from normal MVC to using .Net Core in the last 30 minutes?!

Comment: no need to question my intentions, I have asked about SimpleMembership instead of Identity, if you know the answer, please share, if don't, please don't comment, since it does not help me, thanks

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Finally, in case you will look for the solution, here is how I mange to accomplish that in ASP.NET Core:

ApplicationDbContext.cs:

```
    protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder builder)
    {
        base.OnModelCreating(builder);

        builder.Entity<ApplicationUser>().ToTable("ProjectName_Users");
        builder.Entity<IdentityUserRole<string>>().ToTable("ProjectName_UserRoles");
        builder.Entity<IdentityUserLogin<string>>().ToTable("ProjectName_UserLogins");
        builder.Entity<IdentityUserClaim<string>>().ToTable("ProjectName_UserClaims");
        builder.Entity<IdentityRole>().ToTable("ProjectName_Roles");
        builder.Entity<IdentityRoleClaim<string>>().ToTable("ProjectName_AspNetRoleClaims");
        builder.Entity<IdentityUserToken<string>>().ToTable("ProjectName__AspNetUserTokens");
    }
```